How can I license a project to be as "open" as possible, but deter commercial machine learning models from being trained on outputs?
Are there any licenses or strategies (dual license, etc), that make it difficult to commercialize machine learning (ML) models made from the outputs of a software library? For example this discussion presents some strategies for having libraries that are open/close to open, but difficult to commercialize.
I'm looking for something similar. However, I'd specifically prevent commercial ML models from being trained on outputs from that library, and allow all other activities.
The scenario I imagine is a big dataset being generated using this library and used to train a ML model. Because the outputs get baked into the model, I don't think using a more restrictive copyleft license helps - no code ever gets distributed. The copyleft license is also not ideal because I don't want to inhibit all commercial activities, just those using ML.
I've looked at the discussion here and here, but feel my question is different because I'm looking to restrict use of the outputs of my library, not the code of the library itself.
If it helps, I ask because I'm writing a "open-source" project. I'd like people to feel comfortable contributing to the project and using it. However, I don't like the idea of a large company making a dataset with the library and training a ML model that could replace the users it's being built for...

May I strongly suggest you read Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?, and Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?  Because between them it seems to me they answer your question ("you can't force a licence on the output of your library, and if you could, questions about how to prevent commercialisation are off-topic here").  If you still think there's anything to your question that is on-topic and unanswered, please say what.

As mentioned in the question Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?, the license of an application or library does normally not affect the license of the output generated with that application/library. The main exception to this is if the output, by necessity, contains a significant amount of intellectual property of the application/library authors.
You have not stated what kind of output your library creates, but chances are that the output will not be a derivative work of the library and in that case copyright law has no way to control how that output gets used.

The other problem is that, even if you could somehow control the output, the copyright status of AI models is extremely murky in most jurisdictions. If you cannot demonstrate substantial similarity or your jurisdiction's equivalent, then you (probably?) have no case even if they did train on your copyrighted materials.
